# Stuck at "unpacking" while trying to install or remove a package

Tags: apt, software-installation

I tried to install a package, I forced it to stop then when I wanted to remove the package, it was stuck at "unpacking..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you haven't already, press CTRL+C to terminate. If it doesn't work, do CTRL+Z and then the following:

   `sudo pkill -9 apt`

   `sudo pkill -9 dpkg`
2. Now run the following command before proceeding to force-remove

   `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
3. Force to remove the package

   `sudo dpkg --purge --force-remove-reinstreq <name of your package>`
4. Make sure you still have space left on your device. It's sometimes the reason why the installation is failing.
5. Clean the cache and update APT

   `sudo apt-get clean`

   `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: this not working for me. still apt hangs on Unpacking....